# JPA @Lob property encoding not working with PostgreSQL text

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, jpa, encoding, lob

## JPA Mapping

I'm Using JPA with Hibernate. I have an entity with a **@Lob** property

```
@Column(nullable=false)
@Lob
private String text;
```

I'm using PostgreSQL 8.4 and the Entity was correctly mapped with the column

```
"text" text NOT NULL
```

My view pages are using UTF-8 encoding and my URL Connection is also using the proper encoding:

```
<property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://myhostip:port/mydb?useUnicode=yes&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8" />
```

Also, my **client_encoding** on posgreSQL is **Unicode** (using Query Tool) or **UTF-8** (using psql).

## The problem

Although I can read/persist the data, when I display it there are some encoding problems like showing ��.

Another information is, on the same entity I have another *String* properties there are displayed correctly for the same content of the @Lob property.

I have also exported the **text** property from *psql* to a *test.txt* file and the content is ok.

I've tested the value of the property just before persisting (debugging) and the value is correct.

Comment: FYI: the correct PostgreSQL's JDBC parameter is `charSet=UTF-8` ([for 8.4 too](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/84/connect.html#connection-parameters))

Answer (score 2):

Based on [this](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-6127) try to add annotation `@Type(type="org.hibernate.type.StringClobType")` after `@Lob`

Comment: That's it @D0dger! Solved my problem! Thank you very much!

Comment: In the latest it's not working. Class not found org.hibernate.type.StringClobType

Comment: Have you tried `org.hibernate.type.MaterializedClobType`?